# My computer says it supports 802.11 for WiFi modules. I am not sure if it is 802.11 a/b/g/n. How ,may I know it in a fedora OS?

Tags: wifi-configuration

I am not able to connect my laptop to 5GHz bandwidth WiFi connections. When I checked my laptop configurations using iwconfig command, it displayed IEEE 802.11. But I am not sure what kind of adaptor is that.

Comment: There are only a few 802.11 devices that support 5.0 GHz.  Simplest way of identifying what revisions of the 802.11 are supported is to identify that part number of the device